# What is the product of a Dieckmann condensation of dimethyl adipate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

**My attempt:** $\ce{MeO-}$ preferably gives SN2 *or* E2, being a strong base and good nucleophile. But which reaction proceeds in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I've given a strong hint by changing the title of your question!*

- Methoxide as a base can abstract a proton from an acidic $\alpha$-position of an ester, that is from $\ce{-C\color\red{H}_2COOMe}$.
- The resulting carbanion/enolate can add to the other ester group of your starting material.
- The cyclic intermediate eventually loses methoxide to form ...

This *Dieckmann* condensation is the intramolecular variant of a *Claisen* condensation.

*I suggest to do it on paper!*

> [image: Dieckmann condensation of methyl adipate]

Comment: The only problem here is OMe- is not a good leaving group. So why does it leave? I think it owes to great stability of C=O bond.

Comment: OMe is able to leave in this instance because the reaction is under basic conditions, therefore OMe is already in solution (so it is stabilized by these conditions).